# Wrong data type for free() in Fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I've been asked to use a library provided [here](http://projects.ce.berkeley.edu/feap/feappv/) and I was following the instructions to build it in Windows, those are located [here](http://projects.ce.berkeley.edu/feap/feappv/README_IntelVS.txt).

Now I downloaded Intel Parallel Studio XE as requested and did everything as in the instructions but there's a problem inside the code that I can't figure out completely how to solve it. The compiler says `Error #6362: The data type(s) of the argument(s) are invalid.`.

The lines that give trouble are both the same: `call free(adr(n))`

And the declaration of `adr(n)` is what I don't know if it is correct or not since I haven't touched FORTRAN 77 in a while. It is: `adr(n) = malloc(length*ipa)` where `ipa` and `length` are properly defined but I don't know if `adr(n)` is already defined somewhere else in the header files. Should I just add a declaration at the top (I heard FORTRAN needs declarations at the top) or should I do something else? What I know is that `adr(n)` should be `length*ipa` bytes but not if it should be a specific type or not, and I don't remember how to do something along the lines of `char * adr = (char *) malloc(length*ipa);` as I would do in C.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran], your question is not specific to Fortran 77 anyway and `free` is not standard Fortran at all.

Comment: I think you need to provide more context. One line is not enough. Please take the welcome [tour] and see [mcve] about useful code samples. External links are not enough, the code must be shown *here*.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked and answered at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/801638 The source being used declared the variable as integer*8 (nonstandard), but a 32-bit build was being done. Since the Intel compiler treats malloc and free as intrinsics, it detected the mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

In Fortran when you pass an array to a subroutine you do not include an index. By passing `adr(n)` you are only passing the nth element of adr to the subroutine. You most likely want to pass the whole array like this:

```
call free(adr)
```

If this does not do it, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you take the [tour.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: In general the statement that using an array element as the argument passes only that element is not true.  If the dummy argument is an explicit shape or assumed size array (as is common in F77 code) then _sequence association_ is in play.